# How to refresh Graph Input data in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using some Graph view to view some statistic in my project.

e.g. Morish Grapgh, Pie chart graph.

I have an option like date range, so that I can specify the range of date and can fetch the data within that range and show the output graph in the front end.

The issue I am facing is at the First time I am able to see the out put while I am changing the Date range.

from the second time I am able to get the Data from the backend but after setting the new set of values to the graph Data, but the graph view is not changing because the graph is not able to refresh.

Here sample code. Please ask if any additional info needed.

```
   <sa-morris-graph *ngIf="graphData!=null" [data]="graphData"
                           type="area"
                           [options]="{
                          xkey: 'x',
                          ykeys: ['y', 'z'],
                          labels: ['USER', 'New USER']
          }"></sa-morris-graph>
```

from the Component type script file I am setting **graphData**

```
 export class GAUserComponent implements OnInit{
     fromDate : any ;
     toDate : any ;
     graphData : any = null;

     dateSelected(){
          this.gaService.getGaData(this.req,"/users")
    .subscribe( 
        data => {
            this.dataResponse = data;
            let grData = [];
            for (let data of this.dataResponse.usersByDate) {
                var sample={"x": data.valueX ,"y": data.valueY , "z" : data.valueZ };
                grData.push(sample);
            }

            this.graphData = grData;
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Error occered : "+ err);
        }
       );
     }
```

Please suggest me to solve the problem.
I guess In angular 1 there is a watch() to achieve this but in angular 2 this function is not there. 
correct me If I am wrong and help me solve this

Thanks

Comment: Are you using OnPush as the changedetection strategy?

Comment: No I am not using onPush, can you please help me how to do this.

Comment: You could try `this.graphData = Object.assign({}, grData);` but idk if that is the issue.

Comment: Is it Angular or AngularJS? You tagged both.

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly you could use a BehaviourSubject | Obeservable and the async Pipe  ?  So your graph would directly subscribe to the graphData BehaviourSubject | Obeservable